# (A,B) regular => there is a scalar s such that A+s*B is regular ??

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Given two matrices $A,B \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, is it true that $rank([A,B])=n \implies \exists s\in \mathbb{C}: rank(A+sB)=n$

It seems to me this could be easily proved by writing both in Jordan normal form. Am I mistaken? Is there a result I could use, or can someone suggest a name for the problem so I could google it?

If this is true, then does

Given two matrices $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, is it true that $rank([A,B])=n \implies \exists s\in \mathbb{R}: rank(A+siB)=n$

also hold?

Comment: What do you mean by $[A,B]$? The commutator?

Comment: Is $[A,B]$ the $n\times 2n$ matrix obtained by juxtaposition?

Comment: Yes, Hagen is correct. Sorry, I thought that was standard notation :(

Comment: @ereb104 There are [too many standards](http://xkcd.com/927/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \qquad B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Ok, now I feel silly. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can not Jordan normalize two matrices simultaneously.

Hint: what if $\det(A+sB)$ as $s$ goes to infinity.